# Sitemesh3 properties

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, sitemesh

What kind of property can be assigned to sitemesh tag?
I know about 3:

```
<sitemesh:write property="body"/> 
<sitemesh:write property="title"/> 
<sitemesh:write property="head"/>
```

I try to assign div or section, but without success. Do you know another tags?